# What is a graph defined by a recurrence relation called

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, recurrence-relations

Say I have a set of graphs $\mathcal{G}$ defined by a base graph $G_0=(V_0, E_0)$ and a recurrence relation $f:G_i\mapsto G_{i+1}$. Does such a graph or set of graphs have a name? If not, is there a term from set/group theory or abstract algebra that is appropriate?

Comment: What's wrong with "a recursive sequence of graphs"?

Comment: @MishaLavrov There's nothing wrong with that, there just doesn't seem to be much literature on the subject. I just want to be sure there isn't a blind spot in my survey simply because I don't know the proper term for such a graph.

Comment: I don't know of any more specific terms. A specific example of this is the [sequence of iterated Mycielskians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian#Iterated_Mycielskians) and you'd think if there were a more specific term it'd get used there.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I wasn't aware of the Mycielskians, and I agree that the Wikipedia entry for them would probably mention the term if it were a thing. Feel free to turn your first comment into an answer and if no one pipes up with a better term over the weekend then I'll accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just call such objects a recursive sequence of graphs.

There are several places in graph theory where graph sequences come up, and I've never encountered any special terminology for them:

- I've already mentioned the [iterated Mycielskian construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian#Iterated_Mycielskians) in a comment.
- One might construct a sequence of good expander graphs iteratively using the [zig-zag product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zig-zag_product), though there we're not too interested in the sequence itself, just that there exist arbitrarily large graphs with this property.
- In the study of graph limits, we discuss convergent graph sequences (sequences of graphs $(G_n)$ such that the density of any fixed induced subgraph $H$ has a limit as $n \to \infty$).

Often people do talk about "families" of graphs rather than "sequences" of graphs, even if the graphs are explicitly indexed by the natural numbers. For example, see [Lévy families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_family_of_graphs). So I wouldn't be too surprised to see the objects you're talking about called something like an "iteratively constructed family of graphs", too.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks Misha!